# mouseover/mouseenter not fired when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the fancy Apple mouse that detects finger movements such as "swipe" and "scroll".

Leaving the cursor fixed on the screen, but using my finger to scroll down my page, the cursor (although fixed) naturally moves over different elements, because *the elements* are moving themselves.

My problem is that when doing that, the appropriate mouseover/mouseenter callbacks don't get called when he mouse cursor is directly above them.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3341183/901048

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most browsers that I've used don't fire mouse events when the page scrolls. You could try listening to the `onscroll` event and using `document.elementFromPoint` to determine what element has moved underneath the mouse cursor when the `onscroll` event fires.

Comment: Firefox does fire the event! But not Chrome...

Comment: @Randomblue as of Oct. 2015, that's the convention amongst most browser vendors, in order to optimize for better scroll performance.

Comment: But how do we get the mouse cursor coordinates for elementFromPoint if the mouse events aren't fired? The answer is not complete.

Comment: Same comment as @Matthew. This answer is not complete.

Comment: [`document.elementsFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint) might be more useful than `elementFromPoint`.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) method is a nice solution here as it does get triggered when the mouse is rolled into an element as you scroll, even while the mouse has remained static.

You could even [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the mouseenter event on mousemove as long as you include some kind of flag/state-check to ensure your mouseenter code doesn't get executed repeatedly on mousemove.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can... short of having a function that runs on a timer to check the position of the mouse against the elements, but the performance hit on that would be astronomical to say the least. Probably should file a bug report with the browser manufacturer and check other browsers to see if the behavior is replicated - Which I'm guessing it will because dont think any browser will fire a mouseover/mouseenter event if the mouse was not physically moved.