# Angularjs ng-mouseleave dont runs when user scrolls by mouse. another solution?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with a template that will change on mouseover and mouseleave:

```
var template1 = '<div data-ng-mouseleave="mouseLeave()" class="slider-banner">' +
    'something...' +
'</div>';
var template2 = '<div data-ng-mouseover="mouseOver()" class="slider-medium">' +
    'something else...' +
'</div>';
```

When user hovers on directive, mouseOver() will run and new template will be compiled.

```
scope.mouseOver = function(){
    Elem.html(template1);
    $compile(Elem.contents())(scope);
}
scope.mouseLeave = function(){
    Elem.html(template1);
    $compile(Elem.contents())(scope);
}
// first run (onload)
Elem.html(template1);
$compile(Elem.contents())(scope);
```

**BUT** sometimes (when user scrolls without moving mouse) mouseLeave() dont runs correctly and wrong template is on directive. why? how to solve problem?

Comment: Can you please provide a plunker?

Comment: Creating a plunker from this part of project was so hard. I found a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325630/mouseover-mouseenter-not-fired-when-scrolling . I know the source of problem now.

Comment: I made an example: http://jsbin.com/odEsEtil/3, it seems like firefox and chrome handle it fine. But **IE** doesn't. what browser have you tested your code on?

Comment: Thanks. i use google chrome. your example is very good and shows that mouseleave works. i solved my problem by adding some eventListeners on scroll and mousemove. i think it was some issues related to time or other weird bugs.