# Activate hover effect when we scroll to the element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, hover

I am having container the triggers opacity changes on mouse hover. The problem is that if somebody has a steady hand and he just scrolls down the page, hover effect is not triggered even though the mouse is on that element but technically it did not move.

If the mouse is moved the effect is triggered but if the mouse position was outside the element when the scrolling started the effect is not triggered.

How to resolve this so that effect is triggered as soon as mouse arrow is on that element?

```
.nav-bar {
    .nav-wrapper-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      opacity: 0.4;
      transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    }

    &:hover .nav-wrapper-overlay {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }

 <div className="nav-bar">
     <div className="nav-wrapper-overlay" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Is there some code you can share with us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make page scrolling trigger mouseover events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341183/how-can-i-make-page-scrolling-trigger-mouseover-events)

Comment: There isn't really much to share. I added some example .

Comment: Possible duplicate (@Asthmatic showed another):
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927179/div-hover-not-working-when-scrolling-in-chrome#answer-8927572](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927179/div-hover-not-working-when-scrolling-in-chrome#answer-8927572)

Comment: I just noticed something. This effect is not triggered if dev console is open. If it's closed it will be triggered. There will be priority given to scroll effect but as soon as you stop scrolling the hover effect will be triggered if the mouse is on element even if you don’t move it. While developing I never turn off my dev console so I missed that.