# Detect component hover on scroll in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, scroll, react-hooks

As you may already know, mouseenter and mouseleave events are NOT triggered if the mouse doesn't move, which means that if you scroll over an element without moving the mouse, hover effects are ignored.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58661572/3846106) describes the strategy to overcome this:

> 1: Add a scroll listener to the window.
>
> 2: In the handler, call document.elementsFromPoint.
>
> 3: Manually call the actual mouseover handler for those elements.
>
> 4: Manually call the actual mouseleave handler for elements no longer being hovered.

We also must take into account that registering a listener for each component we want to detect the hover of, is a waste of resource.

My idea is to create a singleton object and subscribe to it from each component.
I'm fairly new to react so I will try to write pseudo-react-code to describe my idea:

```
// A global singleton object that registers the listeners ONCE.
class Singleton {

    subscribedElements = {}

    subscribe(element, isHovered, setIsHovered) {
        subscribedElements[element] = {
            isHovered: isHovered,
            setIsHovered: setIsHovered
        }
    }

    unsubscribe(element) { ..... }


    constructor() {
         window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
         window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMove);
    }


    handleMove() {
        //omitted
    }
   
    handleScroll() {
        hoveredElements = document.elementsFromPoint(mousePosition)

        // Iterate every element that is subscribed and check if they are in the list of elements that are hovered.
        subscribedElements.map( e => {

            if (hoveredElements.contains(e)) {
                subscribedElements[e].setIsHovered(true)
            } else {
                subscribedElements[e].setIsHovered(false)
            }
        })
    }

}

// a hook to be used in all elements that want to detect if they are hovered
function useHovered(element) {
    [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
    Singleton.subscribe(element, isHovered, setIsHovered);
    return isHovered;
}

// All components that want to check if they are being hovered would do this
function MyComponent(props) {
     isHovered = useHovered(this);
     
     return <div>{ isHovered ? 'hovered' : 'not hovered'</div>

}
```

Now, what is the most efficient and clean way to do something like this?
I have read about useContext but I'm not sure how to apply it to this solution.

I'm not sure how to create this singleton. Does it have to be a component? Can it be done in the new functional way?